# How to infer types in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which I read in using `pyspark` with:

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/user/me/data/*").toPandas()
```

Unfortunately, pyspark leaves all the types as `Object`, even numerical values.   I need to merge this with another dataframe I read in with `df2 = pd.read_csv("file.csv")` so I need the types in `df1` to be inferred exactly as pandas would have done it.

> How can you infer types of an existing pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the same column names you could use [**`pd.DataFrame.astype`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df1 = df1.astype(df2.dtypes)
```

Otherwise, you need to construct a dictionary where keys are the column names in `df1` and the values are `dtypes`.  You can start with `d = df2.dtypes.to_dict()` to see what it should look like.  Then construct a new dictionary altering the keys where needed.

Once you've constructed the dictionary `d`, use:

```
df1 = df1.astype(d)
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Will this also convert `''` into NaN if the type is float?   This is what pd.read_csv does.

Comment: I don't think it will.  You need to manually convert that column with `pd.to_numeric(df['mycol'], errors='coerce')`