# How to merge pyspark and pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a very large pyspark dataframe and a smaller pandas dataframe which I read in as follows:

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/user/me/data1/")
df2 = pd.read_csv("data2.csv")
```

Both dataframes include columns labelled "A" and "B".  I would like to create another pyspark dataframe with only those rows from `df1` where the entries in columns "A" and "B" occur in those columns with the same name in `df2`. That is to filter df1 using columns "A" and "B" of df2.

> Normally I think this would be a join (implemented with `merge`) but
>   how do you join a pandas dataframe with a pyspark one?

I can't afford to convert `df1` to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: What about converting the pandas dataframe to a pyspark dataframe?

Comment: @5nv How can you do that?  I think there is a problem with types too. pyspark doesn't seem to infer types when it reads in a csv.

Comment: Since we know nothing about how structurally similar your `df1` and `df2` are, it would be very useful if you provide feedback in the answer to this other (and probably related) question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283021/how-to-infer-types-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 12):

you can either pass the schema while converting from pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
StructField("name", StringType(), True),
StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_dataframe, schema)
```

or you can use the hack i have used in this function:

```
def create_spark_dataframe(file_name):
    """
    will return the spark dataframe input pandas dataframe
    """
    pandas_data_frame = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    for col in pandas_data_frame.columns:
      if ((pandas_data_frame[col].dtypes != np.int64) & (pandas_data_frame[col].dtypes != np.float64)):
        pandas_data_frame[col] = pandas_data_frame[col].fillna('')

    spark_data_frame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_data_frame)
    return spark_data_frame
```

Comment: Is there an implicit conversion of some sort happening on the `createDataFrame()` invocation?  What mechanism permits the transformation from a pandas df to spark df in that call?

Comment: i tried it out: corrected an indentation error and then got this: `ValueError: can not infer schema from empty dataset`

Comment: in this function you have provided the csv file_name  with headers right?

Comment: ah!  my bad. I'm used to `parquet` that does it automagically

Comment: And regarding your first question i have some idea but will study some more about that and will share the results have to be sure when answer :)

Comment: inferschema is Deprecated in spark now the same function createDataFrame() can be used to create a DataFrame from an RDD of tuple/list, list or pandas.DataFrame. By the way inferschema only takes rdd as an input and returns a pyspark dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code snippet for your help:

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/user/me/data1/")
df2 = pd.read_csv("data2.csv", keep_default_na=False)
df3 = df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df2, schema)
df = df1.join(df3, ["A", "B"])
```